# Image resizing changes color and texture

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I'm cutting up a large image in to smaller overlapping patches, and [this 500x500x3 gray square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFwQg.png) is part of the background.

I'm loading the image into numpy, attempting to scale it down by to 100x100x3, and then saving the image using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import skimage.transform
from matplotlib.image import imread

im = imread(originalPath)
arr = np.array(im)
resized = skimage.transform.resize(arr,(100,100,3))
misc.imsave("resized.tif", resized)
```

The saved image is the correct size, but [becomes purple and pink rather than the original gray.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxlP9.png)

I've also tried other rescaling methods including

```
skimage.transform.downscale_local_mean(arr, (5,5,1))
skimage.measure.block_reduce(arr, block_size=(5,5,1), func=np.mean)
```

and they all produce slightly varying versions of the same purple-ish square.

I have one main question and one side question:

1. How do I rescale to have a square with accurate colors?
2. Am I using the correct rescaling method?

Comment: I recommend using `skimage.io`; its `imsave` does the right thing.  You can also use the `imageio` library directly, if you prefer.

Comment: Are you sure the resizing is the problem? I.e. what happens if you save the oroginal image, `arr` without resizing?

Comment: `arr` is able to save the original image without issue. `skimage.io.imsave` saves an image with the correct colors and array values when reloaded into numpy, but the saved files are corrupt and can only be viewed in Photoshop